# Error, when trying to save an image using Image.save()

Tags: python, save, python-imaging-library

I have a Problem with some Python code.
I have a folder with Pictures. With a python program, I want to make them that way, that they have fewer pixel.
I have this program:

```py
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

i = 0
width = 32
height = 32

pfad = "C:\\Users\\Leopold\\source\\repos\\bilder verkleinern\\bilder verkleinern\\Pinguin"
pictures = os.listdir(pfad)

länge_pfad = len(pictures)
pfad_save = "C:\\Users\\Leopold\\source\\repos\\bilder verkleinern\\bilder verkleinern\\fertig\\Pinguin\\"

while länge_pfad >= i:
    pfad_echt = "C:\\Users\\Leopold\\source\\repos\\bilder verkleinern\\bilder verkleinern\\Pinguin\\" + \
        pictures[i]
    Bild = Image.open(pfad_echt)
    Bild = Bild.resize((width, height))
    pfad_save = pfad_save + pictures[i]
    Bild.save(pfad_save)
    i = i + 1
```

The problem is, that if I start this, the Error

```
"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\... (this is the file directory)\\1.300px-Falkland_Islands_Penguins_36.jpg1.300px-Falkland_Islands_Penguins_36.jpg10.2012_falkland_antarktis_0124.jpg1
```

But of course, there is no picture like that, because I want, that the program write this to this Folder.
What can I do against that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you provide the full traceback, or the line in which the error occured

Comment: The error occured at Bild.save(pfad_save)